# Getting error 1004 on my output range. Need to specify it correctly

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet with the following data on it:

```
    A          B        C         D          E
SF15-100     MFG1     JOB1    TOTALMFG    TOTALWC
SF15-101     MFG2     JOB1
SF15-102     MFG3     JOB1
```

Im trying to write a loop to go thru column A and determine if that value is the same on a different workbook in a specific range.If its the same then it needs to paste values to the right of it in columns D and E.

i.e If

```
INWBK.Sheets("QTR").Range("H7").Value = "SF15-101"
```

Then

```
        A          B        C         D          E
SF15-100     MFG1     JOB1    TOTALMFG    TOTALWC
SF15-101     MFG2     JOB1    TOTALFOB    TOTALWC 
SF15-102     MFG3     JOB1
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
Private Sub OKBTN_Click()
Dim TOTALFOB As String
Dim TOTALWC As String
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim INWBK As Excel.Workbook
Dim TOTMFG As Variant
Dim TOTWC As Variant
Dim QTR_NUM As String
Dim ILast As Long
Dim i As Long

TOTALFOB = RefEdit1
TOTALWC = RefEdit2

Set INWBK = ActiveWorkbook
Set wbk = Workbooks.Open("C:\QUOTE REQUEST LOG 2015.xlsm")

QTR_NUM = INWBK.Sheets("QTR").Range("H7").Value

ILast = wbk.Sheets("QTR_LOG").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To ILast
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = QTR_NUM Then
        wbk.Sheets("QTR_LOG").Range(Cells).Offset(0, 4) = TOTALFOB
        wbk.Sheets("QTR_LOG").Range(Cells).Offset(0, 5) = TOTALWC

    Else
    End If
Next i
ThisWorkbook.Save: ThisWorkbook.Saved = True

Unload Me
ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

I get errors on:

```
        wbk.Sheets("QTR_LOG").Range(Cells).Offset(0, 4) = TOTALFOB
        wbk.Sheets("QTR_LOG").Range(Cells).Offset(0, 5) = TOTALWC
```

Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: what are RefEdit1 and RefEdit2?

Comment: RefEdit1 is a Subtotal and is a number (i.e.$500), it refers to a cell that the user picks. RefEdit2 is a Total and is a number (i.e.$500), it also is a cell a user picks.

Comment: Sweet i figured it out how to get the RefEdits to work. The problem i have now is when code is done running active workbook and quote request log should be closed but are still open. i tried INWBK.Close and Wbk.close. This did not cose the workbooks

Comment: It's the code resident in the workbook that contains sheet `QTR`?

Comment: Still getting used to some o the terminology, but do you mean is this code in the sheet QTR? If so then, Yes it is.

Comment: Then let's replace these lines:

    `Set INWBK = ActiveWorkbook`
        `ThisWorkbook.Save: ThisWorkbook.Saved = True`

With these lines

    `Set INWBK = ThisWorkbook`
        `INWBK.Save: INWBK.Saved = True`

Comment: This ends the code correctly by closing all the windows, but it does not save the entries that are inputted into Wbk.

Comment: That change was done some time back, with this line `Wbk.Close SaveChanges:=True`  Are you using the latest update?

Comment: Just double checked and everything matches the code below. The only thing that is different is my RefEdit. If i comment out the save and close lines the data is outputted to Wbk like it should be. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: I added the code in my Workbook below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No values were update as the workbook to be compared though declared was not used as the `Cells(I,1)` in this line was not qualified so the procedure was using whatever worksheet was active.

This is your code modified, please try and let me know about the results...
I assigned some values to `RefEdit1` and `RefEdit2` for testing

```
Private Sub OKBTN_Click()
Const kPath As String = "C:\"
Const kFile As String = "QUOTE REQUEST LOG 2015.xlsm"

Dim TOTALFOB As double
Dim TOTALWC As double
Dim Wbk As Workbook
Dim INWBK As Workbook
'Dim TOTMFG As Variant  ' Not Used
'Dim TOTWC As Variant   ' Not Used
Dim QTR_NUM As String
Dim ILast As Long
Dim i As Long

Dim RefEdit1, RefEdit2   'Not declared before

    'Values Assigned for testing
    TOTALFOB = 450
    TOTALWC = 500
'    TOTALFOB = RefEdit1
'    TOTALWC = RefEdit2

    Set INWBK = ThisWorkbook

    Rem Set Wbk in case it's open
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Wbk = Workbooks(kFile)
    On Error GoTo 0
    Rem Validate Wbk
    If Wbk Is Nothing Then Set Wbk = Workbooks.Open(kPath & kFile)

    QTR_NUM = INWBK.Sheets("QTR").Range("H7").Value

    With Wbk.Sheets("QTR_LOG")
        ILast = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To ILast
            If .Cells(i, 1).Value = QTR_NUM Then
                .Cells(i, 4) = TOTALFOB
                .Cells(i, 5) = TOTALWC

    End If: Next: End With

    INWBK.Save: INWBK.Saved = True

    'Unload Me
    Wbk.Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

Suggest to visit these pages:

[Excel Objects](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Objects.html), [If...Then...Else Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg251599.aspx), [On Error Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251688.aspx)

[Range Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx), [Variables & Constants](http://www.excelfunctions.net/VBA-Variables-And-Constants.html), [With Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264723.aspx)

Do let me know of any question you might have about the code and resources used.

Comment: ActiveWorkbook.Close is to close the Quote Request Log after the data has been entered. The above code works to insert the data but does not work with my RefEdits. The RefEdits are boxs on my userform. Do i need to define them? I thought they work like a ComboBox?

Comment: The quote request is Wbk, Isn't it? do not use `activeworkbook` nor `activesheet`, that's what got the problem earlier, use the variables assigned to each object. see edit last to the code. as regards the combobox, please enter another question and show the code you are using for that. So please acknowledge the answer to this question...

Comment: Be aware that you were closing the Quote Request Log workbook without saving the changes....

Answer (score 0):

You miss row and column index in **Cells** function

```
wbk.Sheets("QTR_LOG").Range(Cells).Offset(0, 4) = TOTALFOB
wbk.Sheets("QTR_LOG").Range(Cells).Offset(0, 5) = TOTALWC
```

Comment: you should be more explicit try:
replace these lines:
        `wbk.Sheets("QTR_LOG").Range(Cells).Offset(0, 4) = TOTALFOB`
        `wbk.Sheets("QTR_LOG").Range(Cells).Offset(0, 5) = TOTALWC`

with these:
        `wbk.Sheets("QTR_LOG").Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 4) = TOTALFOB`
        `wbk.Sheets("QTR_LOG").Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 5) = TOTALWC`

It's not just about missing row and column, also range is redundant

Comment: Thanks @EEM. That fixed my error 1004. Would you happen to know why it is not outputting values to wbk?

Answer (score 0):

```
Const kPath As String = "C:\"
Const kFile As String = "QUOTE REQUEST LOG 2015.xlsm"

Dim TOTALFOB As Variant
Dim TOTALWC As String
Dim Wbk As Workbook
Dim INWBK As Workbook
Dim QTR_NUM As String
Dim ILast As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim TOTMFG As Variant
Dim TOTWC As Variant
Dim LR As Long

Set INWBK = ThisWorkbook

With Sheets("QTR")
    LR = .Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    TOTALFOB = WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range("I23:I" & LR))
End With


'Values Assigned for testing
'  TOTALFOB = 450
'  TOTALWC = 500

TOTALWC = TOTALFOB + INWBK.Sheets("QTR").Range("D18").Value


QTR_NUM = INWBK.Sheets("QTR").Range("H7").Value


Rem Set Wbk in case it's open
On Error Resume Next
Set Wbk = Workbooks(kFile)
On Error GoTo 0
Rem Validate Wbk
If Wbk Is Nothing Then Set Wbk = Workbooks.Open(kPath & kFile)  



With Wbk.Sheets("QTR_LOG")
    ILast = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To ILast
        If .Cells(i, 1).Value = QTR_NUM Then
            .Cells(i, 6) = TOTALFOB
            .Cells(i, 7) = TOTALWC

End If: Next: End With

'INWBK.Save: INWBK.Saved = True

'Unload Me
'Wbk.Close SaveChanges:=True

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This will input the correct values into my Quote Request Log. The problem is it will not save the inputted values if i run the save and close parts.

Comment: This code does not compiles due to the last `End If`

Comment: Don't understand why is not saving the changes try this changes: `Dim TOTALFOB As double` `Dim TOTALWC As double` and `Wbk.Save` `Wbk.Saved=true` `Wbk.Close`